# Processing threads and functions

Tags: java, multithreading, processing

I have extended the thread class and I have made a function to load a new gif like so:

```
import gifAnimation.*;

Gif water;
Loader thread2;

void setup(){
thread2 = new Loader("water");
thread2.start();
}

void draw(){
 water.play(); // this returns null pointer exception
}

Gif water(){
water = new Gif(this, "waterloop.gif");
return water;
}
```

so what I expected to happen was:

water is a new instance of Gif class. thread2 is a new instance of the loader class which looks for water function to run. the water function is of type Gif. It loads the waterloop gif. and assigns the new value to global var water when thread2 ends.

the only thing is the the returned value dosen't appear to persist outside of the function any thoughts?

Comment: Just a tip : Unless you are not adding an additional behavior to the thread class use a Runnable instance rather then subclassing the Thread class.

Comment: is return water not supposed to set the value of the global variable. in line 3?

Answer (score 0):

> the only thing is the the returned value dosen't appear to persist outside of the function any thoughts?

I would check

- you can guarantee that `water()` is called before `draw()`. i.e. just because you would like it to be called in that order in different threads is like wishing on a star. (it might happen, but it might not)
- you only one instance of this class. i.e. there is no point calling water() on one instance and draw() on another.

Can you clarify how `setup()` makes a difference here?

Comment: ok sure

each gif is rather big greater than 20mbs
some need to be displayed together. I can see each thread executing 

my code is somewhat bigger than i listed in the above example

Comment: import gifAnimation.*;

    Gif water;
    Loader thread2;

    void setup(){
    thread1 = new Loader("treeG");
    thread1.start(); // x12 for each gif

Comment: followed by 12 images loaded into a PImage array

Comment: @user61026 that doesn't tell me how it calls either of the other two methods, or how you ensure that draw() is not called until water() has updated the value.

Comment: all functions in draw are wrapped in this function if(thread1.rEnd == true &&
      thread2.rEnd == true && 
      thread3.rEnd == true && 
      thread4.rEnd == true && 
      thread5.rEnd == true && 
      thread6.rEnd == true && 
      thread7.rEnd == true && 
      thread8.rEnd == true &&  
      thread9.rEnd == true &&
      thread10.rEnd == true && 
      
      thread12.rEnd == true &&  
      thread13.rEnd == true  ){

Comment: Ill try and link you a copy of my code... hold on a sec

Comment: Here is a link to the [code] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/a77d9dzh59f6kr4/gifsThread.zip)

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question. Have you ensured that the values will be set in a thread safe manner, or not?